# What specific attributes make code able to be executed in parallel?

Tags: parallel-programming

List specific programming concepts that should code adhere to that it will run in parallel. For example, if a block of code does not change shared state, it should be able to be done on another thread. What other such attributes exist? I would imagine there only to be a small number of such concerns by which to evaluate whether code is a good candidate for parallelization, so what are they?  For example SQL Server when creating the execution plans much use these test to decide for each query section whether to run it in serial or allow it to run on another CPU. All I'm looking for is the list of theoretical rules, nothing implementation-specific.

Comment: see [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)

Comment: ...also please note that resource recommendations are off-topic per [help/on-topic]

Comment: I don't think this is actually asking for a "list of things" @gnat. It just happens to be worded awkwardly. It's asking for the concrete attributes a module of code must have in order to safely parallelize. *That* kind of list is finite, unlike the kinds of lost that close reason is talking about.

Comment: @RubberDuck did you read the question? "All I'm looking for is the list of theoretical rules..."

Comment: Yes @gnat I read the question and am looking beyond the fact that the word "list" shows up and into the spirit of both the question *and* the hold reason.

Comment: This is a good answerable question. "What things must be true to safely run code in parallel?"

Comment: @RubberDuck yeah sure. Every other reader / answerer will look into the question and ignore an opening explanation: "List specific programming concepts that should code adhere to that it will run in parallel..." (not to mention that the way you read it sounds as a list too, ""What things must be true to blah blah")

Comment: And that kind of list of not the kind of list that meta is referring to. *There is a right answer here.*

Comment: @RubberDuck The close reason says "or good answers would be too long for this format" - there are entire books written about parallelism and other methods of high performance computing.

Comment: @ThomasOwens except I'm not asking for all the topics in entire books. A section of code is a candidate for running in parallel if it meets A, B, C. That's not too broad and wouldn't take long to answer. If a query engine can look at a section and decide whether it can be run in parallel, the list of decisions it had to make would not be described by entire books.